# How to click OK when a dialogue box opens?

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I want to select OK when the dialogue box opens from asap utilities.

I tried SendKeys.

```
Range("A:A").Select
Application.Run "'ASAP Utilities.xla'!ASAPRunProc", 90
SendKeys "~"
Range("A:AC").Select
Selection.Copy
```

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51707432/edit) to include more information.

Comment: When the dialogue box opens, is the focus automatically on the key you want pressed?

Comment: yes sir thats what i want

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you run ASAP utilities and it pops up the dialog, excel is suspended until the dialog has gone, so it never gets to the next line. What you need to do is to fill the keyboard buffer with the return before running the utility.

```
 SendKeys "~"
 Application.Run "'ASAP Utilities.xla'!ASAPRunProc", 90
```